# Is there any data limit size for ajax xmlhttprequest post method my xhr get cut off?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send some html data to php script using ajax xmlhttprequest post method. But for some reason My XHR POST REQUEST is cut off and not all data get transferred to my doit.php script. However the same html data from textarea form get passed to doit.php script correctly via normal form post method! could you guys help me overcome this problem and be able to pass this html data via xhr request ?

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.mysite.com/doit.php?Name=test&Id=12345",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("outputtext="+siteContents);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should also [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your *siteContents* string:

```
xmlhttp.send("outputtext=" + encodeURIComponent(siteContents));
```

That's because POST variables are delimited by an ampersand (`&`). The problem probably is  that your string is also containing an ampersand which will be interpret as the beginning of a new POST variable.

You could easily check this if you output all received POST variables in your PHP script:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: comfreak many many thanks that worked perfectly. I was spending few hours trying different things! now my data sent correctly without any cut off!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a GET request to me, because of the question mark and name/value pairs in the URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/doit.php?Name=test&Id=12345
```

Here's how to make a POST request with AJAX:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml

Comment: +sitecontents holds the data i want to post!

Comment: Thanks for reply. My post request works but only sends only part of my html data not full data to php page!